# DAX Filters in a Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am using a measure in a card and am having issues with filtering. The measure looks like

```
ThisWeek = 

Var EndDate = 
DATE(
    Year(Today()), 
    MONTH(Today() )+1, 
    DAY(Today() )
)

Var StartDate = EOMONTH ( Today(), -1 )+1

RETURN

Calculate(
    SUM(Table[Forecast]), 
    FILTER(
        Table,
        Table[DatePulled] = Today()
    ), 
    DATESBETWEEN('Date'[Date], StartDate, EndDate)
)
```

This measure calculates the Forecast between the start and end dates, however needs to be filtered on the data pulled date. The problem that I'm having is that Table has two columns named Industry and Classification which are used in slicers for the dashboard. Whenever an industry or classification is selected from their respective slicers the card breaks. Why is this happening and is there a way to fix it?

Please see link for image of broken card.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiakd.png)

Comment: When you say the card breaks what exactly do you mean, can you show an image?

Comment: Hi, I have made an edit to my original post to show an image of the broken card.

Comment: What is the error message that it gives?